# How can i avoid line break after radiobutton, make going it to a new line only with it's label, not separately

Tags: html, css, line-breaks

I have a code like this:

```
<div class="days" style="width:300px;">
<input id="monday" type="radio" name="monday" value="1">
<label for="monday"> monday</label>
<input id="tuesday" type="radio" name="tuesday" value="2">
<label for="tuesday"> tuesday</label>
<input id="wednesday" type="radio" name="wednesday" value="3">
<label for="wednesday"> wednesday</label>
<input id="thursday" type="radio" name="thursday" value="4">
<label for="thursday"> thursday</label>
</div>
```

And here is jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/k96x02qL/

So as you see, for some values of width of the main div, sometimes there is a situation, when label is on a new line, but radiobutton is not (picture one):

[picture one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0ktn.jpg)

So i want to see something like this (with any value of width of main div) (picture two):

[picture two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGCmj.jpg)

How can i implement it? For some reason i can't wrap input and it's label in one more div. Only can add some styles using "name" html attribute or something like this...

Comment: Are you saying it isn't possible to wrap the input in its label (ie not create any extra elements, but reorganise what you've got).

Comment: Try to place the inputs inside their labels.

Comment: I can't do this for some reason. This part of code is unchangable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without changing the HTML by not showing the input button (opacity: 0) and putting a 'pretend' button in a pseudo element before each label.

This snippet uses a couple of Unicode circles to do this but of course you may want to do it another way - e.g. a background radio gradient or an image.

This way the label as a whole goes across whole if there isn't room for it at the end of a line.

```css
input {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px
}

input:checked+label::before {
  content: '\26ab';
}

label {
  position: relative;
}

label::before {
  content: '\26aa';
  margin-right: 5px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="days" style="width:300px;">
  <input id="monday" type="radio" name="monday" value="1">
  <label for="monday"> monday</label>
  <input id="tuesday" type="radio" name="tuesday" value="2">
  <label for="tuesday"> tuesday</label>
  <input id="wednesday" type="radio" name="wednesday" value="3">
  <label for="wednesday"> wednesday</label>
  <input id="thursday" type="radio" name="thursday" value="4">
  <label for="thursday"> thursday</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested [label/component](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) to frame the radio component as a single box, after that add flex layout to styled the main container (`div` with class `.days`) with `flex-wrap: wrap` css property to auto add line break when content is bigger than container `width`:

```css
.days {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="days" style="width:300px;">
  <label for="monday">
    <input id="monday" type="radio" name="monday" value="1"> monday
  </label>

  <label for="tuesday">
    <input id="tuesday" type="radio" name="tuesday" value="2"> tuesday
  </label>

  <label for="wednesday">
    <input id="wednesday" type="radio" name="wednesday" value="3"> wednesday
  </label>

  <label for="thursday">
    <input id="thursday" type="radio" name="thursday" value="4"> thursday
  </label>
</div>

<br/>
Variant for your case:
<div class="days" style="width:300px;">
  <div>    
    <input id="monday" type="radio" name="monday" value="1">
    <label for="monday"> monday</label>
  </div>  

  <div>    
    <input id="tuesday" type="radio" name="tuesday" value="2">
    <label for="tuesday"> tuesday</label>
  </div>  
  
  <div>
    <input id="wednesday" type="radio" name="wednesday" value="3">
    <label for="wednesday"> wednesday</label>
  </div>  
  
  <div>
    <input id="thursday" type="radio" name="thursday" value="4">
    <label for="thursday"> thursday</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add an explanation of what and why you are doing.

Comment: For some reason, i can't put input inside label. This part of code is unchangable